# dotnetnuke cant open my page

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, iis-8

Am trying to learn how to use dotnetnuke so am kinda new to it. I installed it correctly and i set up a user in server management studio. So when i try to open my page `localhost\mypage` i get these errors:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       Configuration section not allowed in a <location> tag
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ANTONISDB\web.config
Requested URL      http://`localhost`:80/dotnetnuke
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

Config Source:

```
  210:   </system.web>
  211:   <runtime>
  212:     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```

Anyone knows whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the Application Pool for the virtual directory/application is configured to USE ASP.NET 4.0, DNN won't run with .NET 3.5 anymore (starting with Version 7)

Comment: In application pools i only had .net v2 and .net v4.5, defaultapppool etc. Do i need to set an asp here in the app pools? The only place i enabled asp.net is from Turn Windows features on or off from programs and features, and i went to iis and www and enabled asp.net. I also hav in the isapi and cgi restrictions asp.net v2 and v4

Comment: 4.5 is fine, was it running V2 before?

Comment: You couldn't have had both "on", at the ApplicationPool you define which .NET version the pool runs, what was it configured to be?

Comment: what i meant with both on its that i had in the list a v2 and a v4. the defaultapppool is v4. I fixed the problem yesterday though. I had to format cuz my laptop wasnt going well. And someone who did the dnn installation progress again helped me do it so i quess am ok now. Thanks for the help anw